# Google Chrome Color Problem

Tags: google-chrome

Awhile go as I opened google chrome I noticed the color to be much different and weird, perhaps some contrast issue. As you can see in the screenshots,
 the webpages and toolbar appears to be much darker. Even the incognito new tab doesn't appear to look normal

[Screenshots Below]

**Things I've tried so far**

 - Restarting my computer

 - Cleaning History, Cache and Cookies

[image: Google.com]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Which extensions are you using? Try disabling any accessibility extensions.